# ui-autocomplete , list changes height on hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My autocomplete list changes its height and I can't seem to find it. This happened when I removed the borders , it kind of moves the objects inside.

What class is it I need to change for this to stop happening? As you see in the pictures the height of the list changes every time I hover it for some reason. I have tried changing these classes: `.ui-state-focus` & `.ui-menu-item`

Basically the problem is : I hover and it looks like all the elements are kind of "jumping" to top right corner , this happens after I removed the borders from `.ui-state-focus`

[image: hover]

[image: not hover]

**CSS:**

```
 #ui-id-1 {
   border: 2px solid #e1e4e6;
   border-radius: 5px;
   top: 5px;
 }

 .ui-state-focus {
   background: none !important;
   background-color: #e7eff2 !important;
   height: 62px!important;
   width: auto!important;
   border: none!important;
   padding: 3px 1em 3px .5em!important;
 }

 .ui-menu-item {
   height: 60px;
   width: auto;
 }

 .personSearch {
   position: relative;
 }

 .user-photoSearch {
   width: 35px;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
   left: 15px;
   top: 15px;
 }

 .nameUser {
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   font-size: 0.875em;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   left: 35px;
   color: #35383a;
   top: -5px;
 }

 .positionUser {
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   font-size: 0.875em;
   position: relative;
   left: 70px;
   color: #8b959a;
   top: -5px;
 }
```

**JS:**

```
searchBox.autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../module/listOfNamesCreateNewMsg.inc.php",
      data: {
        value: searchBox.val().toLowerCase()
      },
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data.slice(0, 5), function(obj) {
          return {
            name: obj.name,
            position: obj.pos,
            img: obj.img,
            id: obj.id
          };
        }));
      }
    });
  }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<div class='personSearch'>" + "<img class='user-photoSearch'src='" + item.img + "'</img><p class='nameUser'>" + item.name + "</p><p class='positionUser'>" + item.position + "</p><p class='id' hidden>" + item.id + "</p></div>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="searchName"   multiple="multiple" placeholder="Send message to:"/>
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so we can play around with some sample code?

Comment: Alright will create a fizzle @Yass

Comment: It's hard to make a jsfizzle since i need to upload the php file aswell @Yass any tip?

Comment: Edit your question and add the relevant css, html and jquery.